# How to make a date range search with firebase using admin-on-rest filters?

Tags: firebase, admin-on-rest

I'm using [admin-on-rest](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest) framework and [aor-firebase-client](https://github.com/sidferreira/aor-firebase-client) and i'm trying to figure out how to make a filter by date range in List View.

It seems like firebase doesn't support `_gte` and `_lte` suffixes used in admin-on-rest demo. 
So how can i use or pass `startAt()` and `endAt()` query methods for date ranges to filter List data.